# iam trying to set up a react develop environment getting error in somewhere with yarn

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I am trying to set up a react develop environment getting error kin somewhere with yarn.

I have installed Node.js

```
npm -v
6.14.4
node -v
v10.20.1
```

now in my public html folder i have created the site and installed node js package

yarn install works fine.

```
[edu2mfgitulstagi@st03 edu2mfg-clean-architecture]$ yarn install
yarn install v1.22.4
```

But `yarn clean` and `yarn build` shows error

[edu2mfgitulstagi@st03 server]$ yarn clean
yarn run v1.22.4
$ npm-run-all clean:*
/bin/sh: npm-run-all: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

```
[edu2mfgitulstagi@st03 server]$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.4
$ npm-run-all clean lint compile copy
/bin/sh: npm-run-all: command not found
```

please help me to solve this.Thank you in advance

Comment: maybe give some more information.. what framework? which npm packages? what build scripts? cannot help you with just the information above.

Comment: iam trying to do a react js site .npm -v 6.14.4. after running command yarn install node_modules is installed
this is my package.json
.{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.16.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}

Comment: node_modules is a folder containing packages, not something that can be "installed". seeing your package.json there, you should probably getting started in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html. you'll need at least the react dependencies (`react`, `react-dom`), `webpack`, maybe `babel` etc. there's a bunch of useful packages.